# How to create clickable notifications using pynotify?

Tags: programming, notification, python

Is it possible to show notifications displayed in right top (like these about being connected to a wifi), that can be clicked? Right now I can either create a notification, that can't be clicked or create an ugly notification (a dialog box), that can. I would like to have something non-obtrusive, that can be clicked and perform some action then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some Guidelines for developing Notifications

[Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDevelopmentGuidelines)

Comment: So it seems, that it's simply not possible to achieve that. Frack :-/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible, as Notify-OSD doesn't support actions.

Answer (score 2):

This would be an ideal candidate for [morphing windows](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotificationDesignGuidelines#morphing). Unfortunately they are not implemented yet.

Comment: Yeah, such thing would be awesome. Maybe after last revelations about Canonical contributions Ubuntu will quickly come with this ;-)